# Including ordinal independent variables in a linear mixed effects model (using the lme4 package in R)

Tags: r, mixed-model, data-transformation, ordinal-data, lme4-nlme

I am analyzing data from cohort of 500 calves investigating the impact of disease on growth.

My outcome variables are normally distributed, continuous data. I am using hierarchical models with calf nested within farms and testing for the longer term impacts of disease.

The problem I am having is with how to include disease data. I have variables for the number of weeks a calf had disease and the total score over a validated threshold for diagnosis

[image: Histograms of Calf Disease Data]

As I am inexperienced in uploading images, here are the tabulated results of the data above:

---

```
Disease Duration (weeks) 0   1    2   3   4   5   6 
Frequency               266 128  50  33   8   5   2
```

---

```
Total Score  0   1   2   3    4   5   6   7   8   9  10  13  14  15 
Frequency   266  88  51  30  20  13   2   6   4   5   3   1   2   1
```

---

Obviously, this data is far from normal. But there a lot of levels to use a dummy coded categorical variable, and I think an ordinal scale better represents the data. What do you think it the best way to include this data as an independent variable in my LME models? (n.b. I don't include both in the same model just one or the other)

The models do return results without convergence errors or other warnings when I include these variables but it doesn't feel like very good practice and I am unsure of what sort of transformation I could do to make this data better (e.g. log transformation leaves the data looking very odd and plots of the raw data make it look like a linear relationship is the most likely)

Here is an example of what I would like to improve:

(adj_w_63 - calf weight,
weeks_brd - weeks with disease (as described above),
rid - a normally distributed continuous variable,
milksolids_total - a normally distributed continuous variable)

```
library(lme4)
model1<-lmer(adj_w_63 ~ weeks_brd + rid + milksolids_total + (1|farm_ac),
 data=comp)
summary(model1)

Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: adj_w_63 ~ weeks_brd + rid + milksolids_total + (1 | farm_ac)
   Data: comp

REML criterion at convergence: 3247

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.5180 -0.5525 -0.0458  0.5945  6.1674 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 farm_ac  (Intercept) 30.10    5.487   
 Residual             83.37    9.131   
Number of obs: 443, groups:  farm_ac, 11

Fixed effects:
                 Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)      68.06279    3.30996  20.563
weeks_brd        -1.00200    0.42089  -2.381
rid               0.11010    0.04981   2.210
milksolids_total  0.19904    0.07679   2.592

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) wks_br rid   
weeks_brd   -0.174              
rid         -0.285  0.141       
mlkslds_ttl -0.795  0.038 -0.016
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 9):

(This answer applies to [generalized] linear models generally, not just mixed models.)

[This answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735636/interpretation-of-ordered-and-non-ordered-factors-vs-numerical-predictors-in-m/25736023#25736023) discusses the interpretation of linear models with ordinal independent (predictor) variables. Here are two reasonable approaches, not clear which is best:

- treat the score as numeric. *Advantages*: simple, parsimonious (only takes one parameter). *Disadvantages*: assumes that the degree of change between each successive pair of scores is identical.
- convert the score to an *ordered factor*; in R, this automatically (by default) uses *orthogonal polynomial contrasts*. This will use the same number of parameters as treating the score as an unordered factor (and will give the same overall predictions, goodness-of-fit, etc.), but will give more interpretable parameters in terms of linear, quadratic, cubic ... terms. You *may* be able to reduce the number of terms (equivalent to using a lower-order orthogonal polynomial). *Advantages*: makes no assumptions about the size of differences. *Disadvantages*: less parsimonious.

Depending on what your goal is (prediction, hypothesis testing, etc.), you may be able to find some level of intermediate complexity (by regularizing/penalizing, or more crudely by reverting to lower-order orthog. polynomials, or by fitting a generalized additive model using a spline function of the scores), but the two options above are the simplest.